# igraph: given a list of vertices, find the smallest connected subgraph

Tags: igraph

I have the following problem: I have a relatively large graph and would like to extract a connected subgraph given a set of vertices, which might not be directly connected. Example:

```
library(igraph)
Test <- graph(c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d", "b", "e", "b", "f", 
              "c", "g", "c", "h", "d", "i"))
plot(Test, layout=layout_as_tree)
```

now I would like to extract the (smallest) subgraph that contains e.g. vertices `"e"`, `"c"` and `"g"`.
Is there an easy way to do that in the igraph package?
thanks for any suggestions!

cheers, jo

Comment: The smallest connected subgraph is a single vertex, no?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I meant a subgraph that contains all vertices (i.e. `"e"`, `"c"` and `"g"` with all additional vertices that are connecting them).

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It's easy with igraph:

```
subnodes <- c("e", "c", "g")
needNodes <- character()
## loop through all nodes and calculate the path to each other node
for(i in 1:(length(subnodes)-1)){
    paths <- shortest_paths(Test, from=subnodes[i], 
                           to=subnodes[(i+1):length(subnodes)],
                           mode="all")
    needNodes <- unique(c(needNodes, unlist(lapply(paths$vpath, names))))
}
## subset the graph
subGr <- induced_subgraph(Test, vids=needNodes)
## looks good:
plot(subGr, layout=layout_as_tree)
```

Thanks for the nice igraph package!

cheers, jo