# How to find minimum vertices that connect certain vertices to each other

Tags: python, combinations, graph-theory, brute-force, branch-and-bound

I want to find minimum vertices that connect certain vertices to each other. For example, assume list of  edges is `connections = [(2,0),(0,5),(2,3),(3,4),(0,4),(4,1),(5,1)]` and the graph will be like below:

[image]

Then I want to know how to connect vertices `2, 4, 5` together with minimum number of vertices. Which in this case is vertex `0`.

Therefore the output should be `[0,2,4,5]` which means 4 vertices needed. I tried to implement the algorithm with brute force since there would be more complicates cases but I am not sure how to find the best answer from all possible combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations

verticis = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
connections = [(2,0),(0,5),(2,3),(3,4),(0,4),(4,1),(5,1)]
key = [2,4,5]

i, j = 2, len(verticis)
res1 = [com for sub in range(j) for com in combinations(verticis, sub + 1)] 
res2 = [com for sub in range(i - 1) for com in combinations(verticis, sub + 1)] 
res = list(set(res1) - set(res2))
```

Comment: This is not shortest path problem. I want to connect those 3 nodes to each other with minimum possible number of nodes.

Comment: Very interesting question! If you don't find a satisfying answer here, perhaps you could try [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Related questions: [pyhon: minimum connected subgraph containing a given set of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975763/minimum-connected-subgraph-containing-a-given-set-of-nodes), [igraph: given a list of vertices, find the smallest connected subgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718224/igraph-given-a-list-of-vertices-find-the-smallest-connected-subgraph), [R, igraph: extract a connected subgraph from a subset of vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367765/extract-a-connected-subgraph-from-a-subset-of-vertices-with-igraph).

Comment: See also: [Wikipedia: minimum Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem)

Comment: What do you mean by `Therefore the output should be [0,2,4,5] which means 4 vertices needed.`. I understand the line before that but this one confuses me a bit.

Comment: It means node 0 can connect nodes 2, 4 and 5 to each other. I have this combination [0,2,4,5] in res but I am not sure how can I pick it as  a best answer.

Comment: Suggestion: Write a function `is_connected` that tells you whether a graph is connected or not. Then, using vertices which are not in your selected set [2, 4, 5], enumerate in order: all sets of 0 vertices; all sets of 1 vertices; all sets of 2 vertices; etc (possibly using functions from module `itertools` to help you). Then, for every set of vertices, generate the set of edges which use only vertices from this set plus vertices from your set [2, 4, 5]. Use function `is_connected` to tell you whether this subgraph is connected or not. If it is connected, halt and return this set of vertices.

Comment: What do you mean by all sets of 0 vertices...?

Comment: Well, there is the empty set :) I'm only talking about "extra" vertices, vertices not in your set of interest, so the empty set represents "don't add any vertices and check if the induced subgraph is already connected"

Answer (score 0):

This problem is in fact a well-known NP-hard combinatorial optimization problem: [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem).

> Given an undirected graph with non-negative edge weights and a subset of vertices, usually referred to as **terminals**, the Steiner tree problem in graphs requires a tree of minimum weight that contains all terminals (but may include additional vertices) and minimizes the total weight of its edges.

In other words:

> A minimum Steiner spanning tree (or simply Steiner tree) of S is a tree of minimum total length whose nodes are a superset of the given set S. Those nodes that are not points of S are generally called **Steiner points** ([source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/steiner-tree-problem)).

Because of the intrinsic hardness of the problem, exact approaches for obtaining a minimum Steiner tree are all of exponential worst-case time complexity (unless P=NP). You can find various exact solution approaches to the problem in the literature. However, one simple exact approach is to model the problem instance in hand to a [constraint optimization problem (COP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_optimization_problem), and solve it using a COP solving tool like [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/):

```
include "steiner.mzn";
var int : weight;
array[1..6] of var bool: vertex;
array[1..7] of var bool: edge;

constraint vertex[3] = true;        % v2 is a terminal
constraint vertex[5] = true;        % v4 is a terminal
constraint vertex[6] = true;        % v5 is a terminal
constraint steiner(6,7,[1,1,1,2,2,4,4],[3,5,6,5,6,3,5],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],vertex,edge,weight);

solve minimize weight;
```

In this code, the boolean decision variable `vertex[i]` indicates that whether or not the Steiner tree contains the (i-1)th vertex . In the instance you described we have three terminals. Therefore, we need to set the value of the corresponding decision variables as `true`. The objective of connecting these three nodes using minimum number of vertices is equivalent to finding a minimum Steiner tree, provided that the edge weights are all one. Hence, in the global constraint `steiner`, we set all the edge weights to one. An optimal solution to the given instance is as follows:

```
----------
weight = 3;
vertex = array1d(1..6, [true, false, true, false, true, true]);
edge = array1d(1..7, [true, true, true, false, false, false, false]);
----------
```

As can be seen, only the vertex 0 need to be employed as a Steiner point (`vertex[1]` is `true` in the returned solution), and the corresponding Steiner tree has three edges (i.e., {0,2}, {0,4}, and {0,5}). For more information on the global constraint `steiner`, see [this link](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-globals.html#graph-constraints).